# defining a variable to output innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I've included the HTML code to give the whole picture of what I am trying to understand.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Echo App</title>

</head>
<body>
<p>Echo</p>
<p>Say what? <input id="sayThis" size="40" /></p>
<p>How many times? 
<select id="howMany">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
</select></p>

<p><button onClick="doLoop()">Do it!</button></p>
<p><div id="results"></div></p>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function doLoop() {

var sayWhat = document.getElementById("sayThis").value;
var maxLoop = document.getElementById("howMany").value;

var str = ""; // where we'll store our output temporarily
for (var i=1; (i<=maxLoop); i++) {
    str = str + i + ":" + " " + sayWhat + '<br>';

}

document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=str;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How would the code be written out for this use of 'str'

```
str = str + i + ":" + " " + sayWhat + '<br>';
```

And, more especially, how would the code be written out for this use of 'str'

```
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=str;
```

I look forward to your replies/answers. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

your code works fine, look at it here :-)

http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/s8fyQ/

The **reason** why it works:
This is because `str` is first set as an empty string, ad as you go through the loop you add on more text.
`document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=str;` sets the html of the element with the `id=results` to whatever is inside of the `str` variable that you set earlier

**UPDATE**

Instead of using `str` you can do:

```
   for (var i=1; (i<=maxLoop); i++) {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = 
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML + i
                + ":" + " " + sayWhat + '<br>';
    }
```

Comment: He's actually looking as to why it works if I'm not mistaking.

Comment: Thank you, Neal, for explaining.  I do understand why it works, what I want to know is how do I write the code and not use a variable, in this case, "str".  For example:

Comment: @Audrey you need the variable or else you wont be able to save the information in the for loop unless for every instance of the loop you do: `document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = document.getElementById("results").innerHTML + i + ":" + " " + sayWhat + '<br>';` which you can do

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to understand why it works, it's simple.

Your code creates a new variable, adds new text to that variable in each iteration of the loop and then sets the value of innerHTML. When you set the value of innerHTML, the browser triggers a behavior which causes it to dynamically update the tag you told it (results).